# Unknown Unity Errors - Assertion and Persistent Manager

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, assertion

Get both of these unknown errors in one of my recent Unity projects (I am quite early in development right now and want to get these problems ironed out in case they become big further down the line)
[Errors in console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meRy5.png)

Comment: What version of unity are you using?

Comment: Please don't add code and output as Images but copy past the raw text here and format it using the `{ }` button for code or the prefix `>` for output